# Is there a way to watch the Final Fantasy XIII cutscenes a second time?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

Is there any way to watch specific Final Fantasy XIII cutscenes after finishing the game?  Some of them are extremely well rendered and I would love to watch them again, but I really don't have the time to replay the game in order to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In similar fashion to most other Final Fantasy games, there is no way to simply watch the cutscenes on your console after finishing the game. Short of saving before every cutscene, no method exists to replay them without replaying the entire game.

However, many of the cutscenes are [posted on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=final+fantasy+xiii+cutscenes+hd&aq=1&oq=final+fantasy+xiii+cutscenes), and are available in 720p (HD) quality.

Comment: Actually, I think you might have been able to in FFX...maybe that was just music though.

Comment: Indeed you can in Final Fantasy X, inside the theatre dome in Luca. However, it's the exception to the rule.

Comment: @Keannu You can only see very few cutscenes(I believe you can see only the pre-rendered ones)